# Methods onLocationChanged

Tags: java, android, google-maps, locationmanager

I'm trying to run a method when the current location changes. It calculates the distance each time the current location changes and then displays it in a textview.

```
public GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //  final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FakeCallScreen.this, R.raw.mysoundfile);

 // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();



    }else { // Google Play Services are available
        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();
        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);    
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, (LocationListener) this); 


        Location marker = new Location("");
        marker.setLatitude(lat);
        marker.setLongitude(long1);

        if(select==false){
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
            t.setText("Please select a marker" + lat + long1);
            Toast.makeText(this, "not selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if(select==true){

            float distanceBetweenPoints = location.distanceTo(marker);
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
            t.setText("Distance to station is "+ distanceBetweenPoints);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Distance is "+distanceBetweenPoints, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(distanceBetweenPoints<1000){
            //do something
        }

    }
}
```

And the onInfoWindow Code

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
    new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            LatLng clickedMarkerLatLng = marker.getPosition();
            lat =  clickedMarkerLatLng.latitude;
            long1 =  clickedMarkerLatLng.longitude;
            String name = marker.getTitle();
            select=true;

            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
            t.setText("Location of "+ name +" is "+ lat + " by " + long1);
```

How would I go about making this run when the location changes?

Comment: put your code inside onLocationChange

Comment: I've done that and it doesn't work

Comment: Post your onLocationChange code.

Comment: Still there is no code for onLocationChange

Comment: it's in the first section of code below the location manager declarations

Comment: No, that is not it. What is your class definition, that is public class .... Also, remove the cast (LocationListener) before this on your requestLocationUpdates line. I suspect you will get an error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... this is in the main activity. and yes, it does cause an error

Comment: What is your class name and extends what?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your class as
`public MyClassName extends Activity implements LocationListener`
And then put your code in `onLocationChanged`